# Confused: Obscure Pliers

Tags: tools, hand-tools

What are these pliers called and what are they used for?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the tool used to clip animal nails. Even looks like it has a handy depth gauge, so you don't hit the vein in a dogs nail.

[Professional Pet Nail Clipper](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FU6PDLU)

[image]

Comment: Very much agreed, the pivot appears to be too thin to support cable cutting of that diameter, which was my first inclination.

Comment: Yep. Used to have a pair just like that with the stop. Never really liked them though.

Comment: Thanks @tester101 Just wondering what it is doing in my brother's electrical tools (we don't have a pet).

Comment: @SkyHigh I can only tell you what it was designed for, no idea what your brother used it for.

Comment: They are not very different from cable shears, such as [Knippex 95 05 165](http://www.knipex.com/index.php?id=1216&L=1&page=group_detail&parentID=1371&groupID=1430) - which happen to be sold as pet nail clippers too.